# Laravel - how to get a parameter of an object in a request file

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.3 and I would like to make a query in requests file which I made to have some validation rules for a form where a user can edit his channel. In that file I would like to make a query which would look something like this:

```
$channelId = Auth::user()->channels()->where('id', $this->id)->get();
```

So that I can get the channel id and exclude it from the rules array, this is how a file looks like:

```
public function rules()
    {
        $channelId = Auth::user()->channels()->where('id', $this->id)->get();

        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:channels,name,' . $channelId,
            'slug' => 'required|max:255|alpha_num|unique:channels,slug,' . $channelId,
            'description' => 'max:1000',
        ];
    }
```

I am not sure how to get the `channel id` of that object that is being updated in the requests file?

Comment: You mean that you don't know how to get the id (which you are using in the example as $this->id) that you sent with the form?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: you are inside Request object that means you can use it's built-in functions for retrieving input: $this->input(), $this->input('id'). Read more on https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a session for that matter, I have stored a key in edit function and then retrieved it in the request file in my query like this and now it works, and the user is not able to manipulate it in the form:

```
$channel = Auth::user()->channels()->where('id', session('channel_id'))->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

When inside of a `Request`object, you can access input as @Silwerclaw correctly said by calling `$this->input("id")` when you have an input with name "id".

When outside of the object, you can use the facade: `Request::input("id")`.

Comment: The problem is I don't have an input with id in the form, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid doing that maybe, since I would like to avoid users having the possiblity of manipulating id?

Comment: Yes, you could do a hidden input like this: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<the id>">`

Comment: From where do you take the ID that you want to submit? If you WOULD make a hidden input, how would you place the ID in the value attribute?

Comment: no, I would like to avoid making a hidden input, in order to avoid any possibility of a user manipulating it in the form

Comment: I understood this. But where do you take the ID you are talking about from? Where does it come from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124698/discussion-between-mrpixeldream-and-marco).

Answer (score 1):

I used model for that matter, in the request file we can access that object by $this and by model name using this we can access all property, So change just as below.

```
$channel = Auth::user()->channels()->where('id', $this->channel->id))->first();
```

But I am not doing like this, i am directly use `$this->channel->id` in rule as below.

```
return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:channels,name,' . $this->channel->id,
        'slug' => 'required|max:255|alpha_num|unique:channels,slug,' . $this->channel->id,
        'description' => 'max:1000',
    ];
```